# IOError: [Errno socket error] [Errno 1] _ssl.c:507: error:140770FC:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:unknown protocol

Tags: regex, python-2.7, windows-8

below is my code i am using to scrap some web page
i am using python in windows 8

```
import urllib
import re

htmlfile = urllib.urlopen("https://finance.yahoo.com/q?s=aapl&ql=1")
htmltext = htmlfile.read()

regex='<span id="yfs_l84_aapl">(.+?)</span>'

pattern = re.compile(regex)
price = re.findall(pattern,htmltext)
print price
```

error i am getting

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>          File "C:\Python27\web.py", line 4, in 
>          htmlfile = urllib.urlopen("https://finance.yahoo.com/q?s=aapl&ql=1")
>          File "C:\Python27\lib\urllib.py", line 87, in urlopen
>          return opener.open(url)
>          File "C:\Python27\lib\urllib.py", line 208, in open
>          return getattr(self, name)(url)
>          File "C:\Python27\lib\urllib.py", line 437, in open_https
>          h.endheaders(data)
>          File "C:\Python27\lib\httplib.py", line 969, in endheaders
>          self._send_output(message_body)
>          File "C:\Python27\lib\httplib.py", line 829, in _send_output
>          self.send(msg)
>          File "C:\Python27\lib\httplib.py", line 791, in send
>          self.connect()
>          File "C:\Python27\lib\httplib.py", line 1176, in connect
>          self.sock = ssl.wrap_socket(sock, self.key_file, self.cert_file)
>          File "C:\Python27\lib\ssl.py", line 387, in wrap_socket
>          ciphers=ciphers)
>          File "C:\Python27\lib\ssl.py", line 143, in **init**
>          self.do_handshake()
>          File "C:\Python27\lib\ssl.py", line 305, in do_handshake
>          self._sslobj.do_handshake()
>          IOError: [Errno socket error] [Errno 1] _ssl.c:507: error:140770FC:SSL            routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:unknown protocol

how to debug this error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use inspect element > go to console > check if any errors in script > manage them > if problem still persists go to network option > now reload the page and check the flow of information > and rebuilt where info. flow is stopped or unexpected.

hope this will solve your problem.

Comment: give feedbacks about the response of your scrapper.